# What is a BLAT file (.blat extension)?

Tags: asp.net, blazor, .net-5

I am building a Blazor WASM application and noticed a file with a ".blat" extension (dotnet.timezones.blat). The file is readable in a text editor and contains coded timezones and geographic information. I can infer the purpose of the file but am wondering what the meaning of BLAT is in this context. I have searched online and have only been able to learn that it is a new extension in .NET 5.0+. Any insights?

(Note: I am assuming it is unrelated to the email console utility.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I can see, `blat` is a format specifically made for blazor. My guess as to the naming is it stands for **BLA**zor **T**ime zones. As far as the file format, it contains timezone data read from [tz database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database#External_links).
You could think of it like a `tar` file, a bunch of tz files packaged together for distribution.
Here is an [old repository showing the creation of the file](https://github.com/dotnet/blazor/blob/master/src/TimeZoneData/Program.cs). (The file extension changed from dat to blat, so the current format is probably different.)

However, from what I can see, currently the blat file is now loaded into the mono runtime from the blazor side as a resource.

[Here is the code on the mono side](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/01cdd1dcaebcc9f2ab36027204142a6703a1b70b/src/mono/wasm/runtime/startup.ts#L559).

[Here is the calling code on the blazor side](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/8a95ee9b8b1bbd41357cd756375d78cec6936116/src/Components/Web.JS/src/Platform/Mono/MonoPlatform.ts#L585).

[Currently blazor uses ICU under the hood](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/24174), I heard they are considering other options though to try get the binary size down in the future.